# mqtt.ping() in Adafruit mqtt library

Tags: arduino, mqtt, ping, adafruit

Following code comes form the Adafruit Mqtt documentation:

```
// Adjust as necessary, in seconds.  Default to 5 minutes (300 seconds).
#define MQTT_CONN_KEEPALIVE 300

// ping the server to keep the mqtt connection alive
// NOT required if you are publishing once every KEEPALIVE seconds
if(! mqtt.ping()) {
   mqtt.disconnect();
}
```

What does the "MQTT_CONN_KEEPALIVE" actually do? I cannot figure it out.. If i write the code as shown above here and put it in my loop, then the ping is executed constantly, and all packets are rejected...  I was expecting that the MQTT_CONN_KEEPALIVE variable is used in the ping() function to execute the ping only if the 300 seconds have passed, but id does not seem to be like that. 
How am I supposed to write the code in order to ping only once every few minutes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MQTT Keep Alive is part of MQTT protocol to maintain a connection between broker and clients. You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901045).

MQTT uses a TCP/IP connection that is normally left open by the client so that is can send and receive data at any time. To detect a connection failure MQTT uses a ping system where it sends messages to the broker at a pre-determined interval if no messages have been sent after a certain period (KeepAlive).

Specific to Adafruit_MQTT implementation, if you publish data and you are sure that you will publish data within the time period set by MQTT_CONN_KEEPALIVE, then you are good to go.

If the server/broker didn't receive data or PINGREQ from client within the MQTT_CONN_KEEPALIVE + an extra of 50% of MQTT_CONN_KEEPALIVE, the broker will disconnect from the network(timeout) and the client will have to re-establish the connection.

So if a MQTT client only subscribe to a topic without publishing, the client then must send the ping (PINGREQ) to the broker at least once in every MQTT_CONN_KEEPALIVE sec. However, you don't want to constantly ping the server. One way of doing it is only send the mqtt.ping() every MQTT_CONN_KEEPALIVE sec.

```
#define MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE 300
unsigned long previousTime = 0;

loop() {
 
  if((millis() - previousTime) > MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE * 1000) {
    previousTime = millis();   
    if(! mqtt.ping()) {
      mqtt.disconnect();
    }
  }

  // do something else
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! very clear.. is there a upper limit for the MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE?

Comment: The KeepAlive in the protocol is 16-bit, so the maximum value is 65,535 which is 18 hours 12 minutes and 15 seconds.

Comment: One tinny hint: time should not be compared with **equal** but with **greater-than** like this: `if(currentTime - previousTime > MQTT_KEEP_ALIVE * 1000)` Why? Because it's very likely that the code will not run at exact time - some milliseconds always get skipped/lost. Otherwise this is a very useful info!

Comment: @knee-cola, you are right, I updated the code with minor change.